# Test Angular Service new BroadcastChannel

Tags: angular

I am trying to write a unit test for Angular service that is going to be a wrapper for `BroadcastChannel` but my test fails with `BroadcastChannel is not defined`. Here is the basis for my simple service and test:

#### service

```
private channel: BroadcastChannel;
constructor() {
  this.channel = new BroadcastChannel('test-channel');
}
```

##### Test

```
describe('BroadcastMessageService', () => {
  let broadcastChannel: BroadcastChannelService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [BroadcastChannelService]
    });
    broadcastChannel = TestBed.inject(BroadcastChannelService);
  });

  it('should be created', waitForAsync(() => {
      expect(broadcastChannel).toBeTruthy();
    })
  );
});
```

##### Failed Test Error

```
ReferenceError: BroadcastChannel is not defined

       7 |   public channel: BroadcastChannel;
       8 |   constructor() {
    >  9 |     this.channel = new BroadcastChannel('test-channel');
         |                        ^
      10 |   }
      11 | }
      12 |
```

I am starting out new to this testing so I look for some helpful feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Is the type of BroadcastChannel just a regular class or is it a service? I’m assuming if you comment out that line in the constructor the error goes away?

Comment: It is the BroadcastChannel API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API